# Chrome Mac don't render very small PNGs very well

Tags: css, google-chrome, png-24, image-rendering

I have PNG-24 exported from Photoshop CS6 and it looks like this in Chrome.

[image]

You can notice white strokes around triangles.

Same PNG renders correctly in other browsers.
Rendering in firefox is like this.

[image]

Comment: I am having the same problem.
Just to illustrate the issue. My hunch is that this only happens with high res mac screens using chrome ![Sample Issue](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JC1Eb.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am having this exact same problem. Seems like when there is very little contrast, Chrome tries to "solve the problem".

After much gnashing of teeth, I found that adding:

```
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Chrome (and Safari) */
```

to the problem element's css solved the problem.

Also, see this post: https://superuser.com/questions/530317/how-to-prevent-chrome-from-blurring-small-images-when-zoomed-in which deals with a similar problem.

Comment: tested it, solved the problem on chrome. thanks, paulcpderson :)